# How to catch up on Dragon Ball Super?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

I've watched DBZ, and ready most of the manga but for the last 3 years I've forgotten about Dragon Ball as I haven't had time to watch DBS or the movies. Well I really want to catch up. But I don't know how. And yes I'm aware how ridiculous this is considering the series is nearing its 100th episode. Please what's the fastest or most reliable way to catch up on it?

Comment: Has an answer here [Do I need to catch up on anything before watching Dragon Ball Super?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/32415/do-i-need-to-catch-up-on-anything-before-watching-dragon-ball-super) In Short, DB and DBGT aren't necessary, but DBZ episodes are a prerequsite, since DBS picks immediately after the Majin Buu Saga

Answer (score 0):

Other than just flat out watching it there are two major routes.

A) Just read the manga, it's kind of close and gives a good summary in broader strokes,

B) Watch the movies battle of the gods and return of freeza then you've just got the zamasu arc and the current arc to watch :-)

For the record questions like this don't really belong here. Since it's so heavily opinionated, and can have no factful approach.

Conversations like that are better on forums like my anime list or other places.